A parabolic–hyperbolic in 3d: $\partial_t u(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{xx}u(x,y,t)-\partial_{yy}u(x,y,t))$
I was just wondering if somebody can provide some references for the parabolic–hyperbolic pde
$$\partial_t u(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{xx}u(x,y,t)-\partial_{yy}u(x,y,t)).$$
Apparently, the IVP problem is ill-posed but I am wondering if anybody has studied it in detail. It will be extra interesting to study any connections with integrable-pdes.
